# Angular 2/4: how is pattern applied in relation to default email validator

Tags: angular

Currently I am trying to map all email inputs with leading trailing space to be `false` in terms of validity. We hve the following input defined:

```
input(#box,[disabled]="disabled", matInput, [(ngModel)]="value", (ngModelChange)="onInputChanged(value, box.valid, box)", type="email",
     placeholder="{{ hintText }}", email, required, pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$")
```

notice the regex in the `pattern` attribute does not allow for a whitespace. Yet, as long as `type="email"` its validity is true when you give a string like " john@company.com". If i simply remove `type="email"` and make it `type="text"` then the validator is properly is applied.

Does angular's default email validator applied / overrides the `placeholder` in the case that they disagree or something?

Comment: Are you lokkimg for this [https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator](https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator)  ?

Comment: sort of... I guess i was wondering what the default interaction of the `EmailValidator` is along with the `pattern` defined on the same `<input type="email">`